# renaming fasta headers in order

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have multiple fasta files and each file with 8 headers always in the same order (in term of species). For example it is like

```
 grep -o -E "^>\w+" batch1.seq

 jgi
 jgi
 augustus_masked
 augustus_masked
 augustus_masked
 jgi
 augustus_masked
 augustus_masked
```

and

```
 grep -o -E "^>\w+" batch2.seq
```

gives

```
jgi
jgi
maker
maker
maker
jgi
maker
maker
```

Irrespective of their headers, I want to rename all fasta headers (8 in number) for the files in the folder to

```
Ara
Soy
Gly
Tom
Whe
Cor
Nat
Blu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'NR==FNR{names[NR]=$0; next} 
        /^>/{$1=">"names[++c]}1' names fasta > fasta.new
```

keep your new header list in the file `names` when using the script.