# Numbering FASTA files

Tags: unix

I have a multiFASTA file i.e. a file containing more than 1 FASTA sequences. Each sequence is preceded by a header which looks like this:

```
>NC_005042.1 etc
>NC_003272.1 etc
>NC_003276.1 etc 
...
```

I would like to rename these headers for numbers, so the output would be like this:

```
 >1
 >2
 >3
 ...
```

In conclusion, I would need to replace each tag after the ">" for a series of ordered numbers.

Comment: Please show what you have done and what went wrong. `awk 'BEGIN {nr=0} /^NC_/ {nr++; print ">" nr; next} 1' fastafile` might be something.

Comment: I tried awk by comparison with a somehow similar case, already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164013/renaming-fasta-headers-in-order

Comment: Still no code in the post …

Comment: Hi, I couldn't post code since I have no clue how would it look like...

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in my comment?

Comment: @WalterA I tried, but not all sequences start with NC_, I also still don't get how awk function works...

Answer (score 0):

When you know that the headers all start with `>` and other lines not, you can use

```
awk 'BEGIN {nr=0} /^>/ {nr++; print ">" nr; next} {print}' fastafile
```

In words: Before eading lines set the variable nr to 0.
When a line starts with `>`, raise `nr`, print header line with `nr` and skip the rest of the commands.
The rest of the commands is only printing the current line.

```
awk '/^>/ {nr++; print ">" nr; next} 1' fastafile
```

is shorter, using default value 0 var awk variables and default print action after `1`.